# How to dispose of a ViewModel in Durandal after Logout

Tags: requirejs, durandal

I might be on the wrong track here, but here goes:

In my PhoneGap Durandal app, I have a Profile View/VM which only returns data the first time it is hit - after that it checks a bool called initialised and wont hit the DB again the 2nd time. This works fine.

However after Logout, I need to invalidate the cache. I could use a message to tell the Profile VM to clear the variable (ie. invalidate the cache) but I thought perhaps there is a higher-level way of doing this in Durandal - e.g. On Logout, I tell dispose of all ViewModels in memory (there may be other Singleton objects with session specific info in them).

Advice please...

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a javascript question and this is just my understanding of how javascript works.

Javascript will automatically dispose of objects that are no longer referenced through a mechanism called Garbage Collection.

Here is a good [article on how Garbage Collection](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_03.htm) works.  Basically it will dispose of objects that are no longer referenced in your program.

There is another method in javascript that allows you to remove objects.  The [delete method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
delete someobj;
```

Which too my knowledge is pretty much equal to `someobj = undefined;`

Hope this helps.

***Edit

Durandal follows the [screen activator pattern](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Model/) for it's viewmodels.  So apart of the viewmodel lifecycle it will call an activate, candeactivate, and deactivate method.

You could do your disposing in the deactivate method.

Comment: using the `delete` keyword in javascript is not the same as setting something to `undefined`.  There are important and significant differences.  Do a quick search here on SO and you'll find tons of info about the differences.

Comment: Thanks Evan, but I was hoping for more of a Durandal Life Cycle type of answer, not HOW to delete them - Durandal manages the state of the objects and hence I could tell it when to dispose of them. I am currently using the messaging aspect of Durandal to send a ClearCache message between my ViewModels but I think there must be a cleaner way using the framework

Comment: Thanks, however it still is not quite what I am looking for - ie. On a certain Event I want to tell Durandal to clear certain data. At the moment I am using ViewModel messaging and subscribing to it in the screens that need to clear data and then manually deleting it, but I was hoping there would be a way in the framework to dispose of certain entities on demand in their entirety.

Comment: gotchya, well if you figure it out please post your answer back here for others.

Answer (score 0):

(Durandal 2.0) You could always hook into the composition life-cycle callback methods on your view-model. There are four: activate(), attached(), deactivate(), and detached(). They are called automatically by Durandal on your view-model, if they exist. In my projects, if I need a view to invalidate its cache, I hook into the deactivate() method and put the cleanup logic there. Similarly, I use the detached() method to unbind events and destroy UI widgets.

Simple example:

```
define(['modules/myDataService'], 
function(dataservice) {
  var cache;

  function activate() {
    return dataservice.getData().done(function(response) {
      cache = response;
    });
  }

  function deactivate() {
    cache = null;
  }

  return {
    activate: activate,
    deactivate: deactivate
  };
});
```

Source documentation: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/